# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' error using Groupby agg(list

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, group-by

**Problem**
So I am trying to aggregate using Groupby my dataset but I've run into this error which I can't really decipher.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/hamza.ahmed/Coding Projects/Client_Works/EPS/EPS_SproutSocial_GoogleSheets_Snowflake_v1.ipynb Cell 25 in <cell line: 1>()
      1 out = post_data_2.groupby(['index', 'content_category', 'post_category', 'post_type',
      2        'customer_profile_id', 'profile_guid', 'text', 'perma_link',
      3        'network', 'sent', 'created_time',
      4        'metrics.lifetime.likes', 'metrics.lifetime.comments_count',
      5        'metrics.lifetime.impressions',
      6        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic',
      7        'metrics.lifetime.post_content_clicks',
      8        'metrics.lifetime.shares_count', 'metrics.lifetime.reactions',
      9        'metrics.lifetime.video_views', 'from.guid', 'from_profile',
     10        'from.profile_picture',
     11        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic_unique',
     12        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid_unique',
     13        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid',
     14        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_unique',
     15        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_follower_unique',
     16        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_nonviral_unique',
     17        'metrics.lifetime.impressions_viral_unique', 'from.screen_name',
---> 18        'title', 'tags', 'Campaigns'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(list)
     19 # or out.fillna('').groupby(['contents', 'posts', 'impressions', 'clicks', 'reactions'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(', '.join)
     20 print(out)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py:883, in DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    878 if result is None:
    879 
    880     # grouper specific aggregations
    881     if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
    882         # test_groupby_as_index_series_scalar gets here with 'not self.as_index'
--> 883         return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
    884     elif args or kwargs:
    885         # test_pass_args_kwargs gets here (with and without as_index)
    886         # can't return early
    887         result = self._aggregate_frame(func, *args, **kwargs)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py:1477, in GroupBy._python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1474     return self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
   1476 for idx, obj in enumerate(self._iterate_slices()):
-> 1477     name = obj.name
   1479     try:
   1480         # if this function is invalid for this dtype, we will ignore it.
   1481         result = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

**My Dataset**

| index_1 | index | content_category | post_category | post_type | customer_profile_id | profile_guid | text | perma_link | network | sent | created_time | metrics.lifetime.likes | metrics.lifetime.comments_count | metrics.lifetime.impressions | metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic | metrics.lifetime.post_content_clicks | metrics.lifetime.shares_count | metrics.lifetime.reactions | metrics.lifetime.video_views | from.guid | from_profile | from.profile_picture | metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid | metrics.lifetime.impressions_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_follower_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_nonviral_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_viral_unique | from.screen_name | title | tags | Campaigns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | VIDEO | POST | LINKEDIN_COMPANY_UPDATE | 4526462 | licp:596893 | Let's celebrate International Beer Day by givi... | https://linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPos... | LINKEDIN | TRUE | 2022-08-06T02:10:17Z | 27 | 0 | 1118 | 1118 | 5 | 2 | 27 | 221 | licp:596893 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQ... | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1141696 | Fun Extra |
| 1 | 0 | VIDEO | POST | LINKEDIN_COMPANY_UPDATE | 4526462 | licp:596893 | Let's celebrate International Beer Day by givi... | https://linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPos... | LINKEDIN | TRUE | 2022-08-06T02:10:17Z | 27 | 0 | 1118 | 1118 | 5 | 2 | 27 | 221 | licp:596893 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQ... | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1141676 | Video |
| 2 | 1 | VIDEO | POST | FACEBOOK_POST | 4530996 | fbpr:259614427411446 | The best way to celebrate International Beer D... | https://www.facebook.com/259614427411446/posts... | FACEBOOK | TRUE | 2022-08-06T00:10:19Z | 4 | 0 | 67 | 67 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 18 | fbpr:259614427411446 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435... | 67 | 0 | 0 | 67 | 50 | 67 | 0 | ErnestPackaging | NaN | 1141696 | Fun Extra |
| 3 | 1 | VIDEO | POST | FACEBOOK_POST | 4530996 | fbpr:259614427411446 | The best way to celebrate International Beer D... | https://www.facebook.com/259614427411446/posts... | FACEBOOK | TRUE | 2022-08-06T00:10:19Z | 4 | 0 | 67 | 67 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 18 | fbpr:259614427411446 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435... | 67 | 0 | 0 | 67 | 50 | 67 | 0 | ErnestPackaging | NaN | 1141676 | Video |
| 4 | 2 | VIDEO | POST | INSTAGRAM_MEDIA | 4530999 | ibpr:17841401555616258 | The best way to celebrate #internationalbeerda... | https://www.instagram.com/p/Cg5YLn9sOhA/ | INSTAGRAM | TRUE | 2022-08-05T23:38:16Z | 10 | 2 | 152 | 152 | NaN | NaN | 10 | 47 | ibpr:17841401555616258 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.288... | 138 | NaN | NaN | 138 | NaN | NaN | NaN | ernest_packaging | NaN | 1141696 | Fun Extra |

**My Code**

```
out = post_data_2.groupby(['index', 'content_category', 'post_category', 'post_type',
       'customer_profile_id', 'profile_guid', 'text', 'perma_link',
       'network', 'sent', 'created_time',
       'metrics.lifetime.likes', 'metrics.lifetime.comments_count',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic',
       'metrics.lifetime.post_content_clicks',
       'metrics.lifetime.shares_count', 'metrics.lifetime.reactions',
       'metrics.lifetime.video_views', 'from.guid', 'from_profile',
       'from.profile_picture',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_follower_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_nonviral_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_viral_unique', 'from.screen_name',
       'title', 'tags', 'Campaigns'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(list)
```

**My Target Result**

| index_1 | index | content_category | post_category | post_type | customer_profile_id | profile_guid | text | perma_link | network | sent | created_time | metrics.lifetime.likes | metrics.lifetime.comments_count | metrics.lifetime.impressions | metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic | metrics.lifetime.post_content_clicks | metrics.lifetime.shares_count | metrics.lifetime.reactions | metrics.lifetime.video_views | from.guid | from_profile | from.profile_picture | metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid | metrics.lifetime.impressions_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_follower_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_nonviral_unique | metrics.lifetime.impressions_viral_unique | from.screen_name | title | tags | Campaigns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | VIDEO | POST | LINKEDIN_COMPANY_UPDATE | 4526462 | licp:596893 | Let's celebrate International Beer Day by givi... | https://linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPos... | LINKEDIN | TRUE | 2022-08-06T02:10:17Z | 27 | 0 | 1118 | 1118 | 5 | 2 | 27 | 221 | licp:596893 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://media-exp2.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQ... | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1141696 | [Fun Extra, video] |
| 1 | 1 | VIDEO | POST | FACEBOOK_POST | 4530996 | fbpr:259614427411446 | The best way to celebrate International Beer D... | https://www.facebook.com/259614427411446/posts... | FACEBOOK | TRUE | 2022-08-06T00:10:19Z | 4 | 0 | 67 | 67 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 18 | fbpr:259614427411446 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435... | 67 | 0 | 0 | 67 | 50 | 67 | 0 | ErnestPackaging | NaN | 1141696 | [Fun Extra, video] |
| 2 | 2 | VIDEO | POST | INSTAGRAM_MEDIA | 4530999 | ibpr:17841401555616258 | The best way to celebrate #internationalbeerda... | https://www.instagram.com/p/Cg5YLn9sOhA/ | INSTAGRAM | TRUE | 2022-08-05T23:38:16Z | 10 | 2 | 152 | 152 | NaN | NaN | 10 | 47 | ibpr:17841401555616258 | Ernest Packaging Solutions | https://scontent-iad3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.288... | 138 | NaN | NaN | 138 | NaN | NaN | NaN | ernest_packaging | NaN | 1141696 | Fun Extra |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the 'Campaigns' inside the groupby method.

Your code:

```
out = post_data_2.groupby(['index', 'content_category', 'post_category', 'post_type',
       'customer_profile_id', 'profile_guid', 'text', 'perma_link',
       'network', 'sent', 'created_time',
       'metrics.lifetime.likes', 'metrics.lifetime.comments_count',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic',
       'metrics.lifetime.post_content_clicks',
       'metrics.lifetime.shares_count', 'metrics.lifetime.reactions',
       'metrics.lifetime.video_views', 'from.guid', 'from_profile',
       'from.profile_picture',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_follower_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_nonviral_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_viral_unique', 'from.screen_name',
       'title', 'tags', 'Campaigns'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(list)
```

My sugestion:

```
out = post_data_2.groupby(['index', 'content_category', 'post_category', 'post_type',
       'customer_profile_id', 'profile_guid', 'text', 'perma_link',
       'network', 'sent', 'created_time',
       'metrics.lifetime.likes', 'metrics.lifetime.comments_count',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic',
       'metrics.lifetime.post_content_clicks',
       'metrics.lifetime.shares_count', 'metrics.lifetime.reactions',
       'metrics.lifetime.video_views', 'from.guid', 'from_profile',
       'from.profile_picture',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_organic_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_paid',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_follower_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_nonviral_unique',
       'metrics.lifetime.impressions_viral_unique', 'from.screen_name',
       'title', 'tags'], as_index=False)['Campaigns'].agg(list)
```